# JOIN changes values to null?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables that have this type of format:

```
Table 1:
Col1:         Col2:     Col3:     col4, col5, col6...
2015-01-01    b         3        
2015-01-01    <null>    5 
2015-01-01    b         5          
2015-01-01    i         6        
2015-01-02    b         4        
2015-01-02    i         5    
2015-01-02    <null>    5  
2015-01-02    i         2
```

And some other columns in the 1st table.
The second table only has the sum of col3 grouped by Col2, thanks to the query:

```
select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3)
from Table1
group by Col1, Col2
order by Col1 asc;
```

So the table 2 looks like this:

```
Table 2:
Col1:           Col2:     sum_Col3:    
2015-01-01      b         8        
2015-01-01      i         6         
2015-01-02      b         4        
2015-01-02      i         7
```

I would simply like to join the column sum_Col3 to table1 yet, because of the null values on Col2, it's giving me somethin odd.

Ideally, the table would look like this:

```
Table 1:
Col1:         Col2:     Col3:     sum_Col3:   col4, col5, col6...
2015-01-01    b         3         8
2015-01-01    <null>    5         <null>
2015-01-01    b         5         8 
2015-01-01    i         6         6
2015-01-02    b         4         4
2015-01-02    i         5         7
2015-01-02    <null>    5         <null>
2015-01-02    i         2         7
```

However, with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.sum_Col3
From Table1 as t1
left outer Join Table2 as t2
ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2;
```

I'm getting the table:

```
Table 1:
Col1:         Col2:     Col3:     sum_Col3:   col4, col5, col6...
2015-01-01    b         3         <null>
2015-01-01    <null>    5         <null>
2015-01-01    b         5         <null> 
2015-01-01    i         6         <null>
2015-01-02    b         4         <null>
2015-01-02    i         5         <null>
2015-01-02    <null>    5         <null>
2015-01-02    i         2         <null>
```

Any insight anyone?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which RDBMS you are using? Is it Mysql or sql-server or any other?

Comment: Sum of col3 query is wrong since you are not taking SUM() function instead you are using Count() which will not give the results shown in Table2 data.

Comment: @NishantGupta
I meant to say count, the values are what I want them to be, don't worry about that. I'm only interested on knowing why I'm getting null values. I'm using PostgreSQL, the graphic version (PgAdmin), not the console one.

Comment: @NishantGupta Actually, thinking about it, you are absolutely right, i should use sum, not count thank you. The question still stands though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why I got null values but, as user @NishantGupta stated, I was making a mistake writing `count(Col3)` instead `sum(Col3)` on the query.

Fixing this, solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should at least change the join expression because it contains an obvious mistake:

from

```
ON t1.Col1 = t1.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2;
```

to

```
ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2;
```

Comment: My bad, that was a mistake in the post, the query was good though so the problem still stands